# Can IntellijJ find usages in JSP via apache taglib and EL

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, el, taglib

In init.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/unstandard-1.0" prefix="un" %>
```

In JSP

```
<%@ include file="/html/init.jsp"%>
<un:useConstants var="ImageType" className="com.mydomain.model.ImageType" />

<select id="amlCheckType" name="amlCheckType">
    <option value="">Please choose one...</option>
    <option value="${ImageType.AML_CHECK_SUBTYPE_VERIPHY}">Veriphy</option>
    <option value="${ImageType.AML_CHECK_SUBTYPE_EQUIFAX}">Equifax</option>
</select>
```

In ImageType.java

```
public static final int AML_CHECK_SUBTYPE_VERIPHY = 135;
public static final int AML_CHECK_SUBTYPE_EQUIFAX = 136;
```

IntelliJ has greyed the latter two out and says they are never used.

Is it possible for IntelliJ to recognise these usages so they do not get deleted by mistake?

Or is there a better way to reference java constants in JSPs, so that they do get recognised?

**UPDATE**

Edition = Community 2018.1

Comment: What version are you using? and what type? Community or ultimate?

Comment: Community 2018.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA community version doesn't support that. You can find this feature in IntelliJ IDEA ultimate version. It has the full feature for the web development including identifying the java variable in `JSP/JSF` page. So I would recommend going with IntelliJ IDEA ultimate version.

Another approach you could follow (Suppress for fields via annotation)

1. You could create an annotation for eg `@Used`
2. Declare your annotation on your declared variable that has been used in JSF

   ```
   @Used
   public static final int AML_CHECK_SUBTYPE_VERIPHY = 135;
   ```
3. Now you can press `alt + enter` in your field and choose `Suppress for fields for annotation ...Used`. Now all the field that has been marked with `@Used` will not complain by the IntelliJ.

**NOTE:** The annotation process is doesn't depend on whether you have used the variable in the `JSF` or not. It simply provides a way to close inspection for marked annotation. If you decide to remove the field from `JSF` you have to come in the `Java` class and remove the variable by yourself. IntelliJ IDEA won't complain that the variable was unused

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I will try it out.